# How to add data to an existing blank dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a blank dataframe with 9 columns and want to have my forloop add data to this blank df but I receive an error whenever I try to run this:

```
temp$age<- age
```

The error is as follows: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, age, value = 1:20) :
replacement has 20 rows, data has 0"

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

R's dataframes are vectorized, think of it as many vectors that, when in a dataframe, are the columns of said dataframe. That means that the different vectors (columns) in a dataframe have to be the same length.

So this will not work:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = NA)
df$age <- 1:20
 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, age, value = 1:20) : 
  replacement has 20 rows, data has 1
```

But this will:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(NA,20))
df$age <- 1:20
```

Hope this clears your problem!